# Do action after upload file with Active Storage

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activestorage

My model has a `has_many_attached :photos`.

The first time this model is created, it has 0 photos. If I run `photos.attached?` I get `false`.

When the user uploads some files to photos, I need to do some actions, but only the first time. I tried using `before_update :if photos.attached?`. But I need to know if the user is updating photos specifically.

Is there a way to know if the user is trying to update photos? Or is there a simple way to do this?

Comment: Let me get this straight: you need to know how to perform an action only the first time a photo is attached to your `model`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is the [dirty?](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Dirty.html) method that you can use

```
class Post < ApplicationRecord
  has_many_attached :photos

  before_update :do_whatever, if: -> { photos.dirty? } 

  def do_whatever
    # doing something
  end
end
```

You might also be able to try  `before_update :do_whatever, if: -> { photos_changed? }`

Comment: I believe the correct syntax for the latter part is `-> {photos.changed?}`

Comment: I could not get this to work.  I kept gettiing the error "undefined method `dirty' for #<ActiveStorage::Attached::Many:0x00007fdaf09e0868>"

Answer (score 0):

Check callbacks (after_create, after_save, etc) in rails models and options "on: :create" and "update".

Answer (score 0):

> Rails has not added the ability to add validations to file attachments. See [Issue #31656](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/31656)

Try this approach:

Validate for `mime-types`:

```
<%= f.file_field :photos, accept: "image/png,image/gif,image/jpeg', multiple: true %>
```

You still need to add model validations. See this post [Validating the Content-Type of Active Storage Attachments](http://www.carlosramireziii.com/validating-the-content-type-of-active-storage-attachments.html)
 on how to use a custom validator.

To limit your `action` to be executed only once, you could add a boolean field to your `model` and set it to `true` after your action terminates successfully. Use a `before_update` as [Antarr Byrd](https://stackoverflow.com/users/504963/antarr-byrd) suggested to check after each photo is attached to your model.